# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: java, shopify

вообще код рабочий но когда добавляю его на shopify то пишет ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

```css
.active{
    color: red;
}
.collaps:hover{
    
}

.content{
     background-color: violet;
     padding: 0 18px;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        }
```

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collaps");
            for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                coll[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    this.classList.toggle('active');
                    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                        content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    }
                    else{
                        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px"
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = this.nextElementSibling;  // content is null
```